# Can I disable the testing of an HTTP Service when generating a schema?

Tags: orbeon

When I use the REST API to generate a schema for a form that includes an HTTP Service, Orbeon checks to see if it is allowed to access the service. See log message below:

```
XFormsServer:214 - checking whether request dispatcher submission is allowed {resource: "https://mycompany.com/mytest-api/v1/clients", noscript: "false", is asynchronous: "false", container type: "servlet", norewrite: "false", local-submission-forward: "true", local-submission-include: "false"}
```

This causes a couple of problems:

1. In this case, calling the service is done as a system call by my application. The system is not granted permission to access the service and that causes a 403 Forbidden error to be logged. This is an annoyance because it looks like there is a problem when there really is none. At run time the user will have access to the service.
2. If I do give the system permission to access the service, then it calls the service without any parameters and the service returns a huge number of records. Orbeon then processes them all with a lot of `xf:action` and `xf:insert`. This uses a lot of CPU and takes minutes to complete. Granted, the service that is being called should probably return 400 Bad Request if no filter parameters are specified, but currently it doesn't.

In either case, this check causes problems. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to disable this right now. I entered [issue #3200](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3200) to track this and we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Erik.